# Can I keep a JDialog from closing on escape/enter press?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I created a dialog to take user keystrokes to change key bindings for menu items. I'd like enter and escape to be keys the user can bind, but they both close the dialog. How can those presses be intercepted?

Edit:
dialog is created with JOptionPane and a custom component

```
GetKeyComponent comp = new GetKeyComponent(accels, menuItem);
Object[] array = { comp };
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(array, 
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: I just realized that escape causes a property change value of JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION, so removing that from the property change listener solves escape.

Comment: and enter does the same thing: it sets the value option to JOptionPane.OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Edit: dialog is created with JOptionPane and a custom component

One solution: don't do this. Create your own modal JDialog, set its KeyBindings, and use it. e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class JDialogTest {
   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame("JDialogTest");

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Push Me") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 30);
            textArea.setFocusable(false);
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog", true);

            int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
            JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) dialog.getContentPane();
            InputMap inputMap = contentPane.getInputMap(condition);
            ActionMap actionMap = contentPane.getActionMap();

            KeyStroke enterKs = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
            inputMap.put(enterKs, enterKs.toString());
            actionMap.put(enterKs.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  textArea.append("Enter pushed\n");
               }
            });

            KeyStroke escKs = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
            inputMap.put(escKs, escKs.toString());
            actionMap.put(escKs.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  textArea.append("Escape pushed\n");
               }
            });


            dialog.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setVisible(true);
         }
      }));

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very viable and helpful solution. In an effort not to rewrite a bunch of code, it worked to consume the enter press just by getting the input/actionMaps of the JOptionPane instance and giving 'ENTER' a blank action

Comment: I'm doing much the same thing as the code above and what @sam wrote, and it works.  What's escaping (no pun) me at the moment is why it only works to assign a replacement do-nothing Action; removing the entry from the action map and also setting the map's parent to null should also do away with the escape action.  But that has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The @HovercraftFullOfEels code as a separate class (with margins and button sizes matching the standard swing (a.k.a. "Metal") look-and-feel):

```
public class SimpleDialog {
    static void showDialog(JFrame parent, JPanel message, String title) {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parent, title, true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        panel.add(message);

        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 10)));

        JButton closeButton = new JButton("OK");
        closeButton.setMargin(new Insets(2, 8, 2, 8));
        closeButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            dialog.dispose();
        });
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(closeButton, new GridBagConstraints());
        panel.add(buttonPanel);

        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) dialog.getContentPane();
        InputMap inputMap = contentPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = contentPane.getActionMap();
        KeyStroke escKs = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0);
        inputMap.put(escKs, "Esc");
        actionMap.put("Esc", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        closeButton.requestFocus();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```