# Execute SQL Statements while JDialog visible?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, joptionpane, jdialog

I am saving A JTable to my SQL Database. No problems with that. However, I wanted to make some kind of dialog that stays on the screen while data from the database is being loaded. I used a JDialog with a JOptionPane:

```
final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Loading", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[] {}, null);
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.setContentPane(pane);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Now, I want the dialog to close as soon as my SQL Statement is executed, however as it seems the dialog keeps the Statement from being executed, as the thread is blocked by it apparently. So, how do I execute my SQL statements while the Dialog is showing and then closes itself after the statement is executed?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can add a propertchange listener to your code.
Found a similar question: [[Java Swing - Close JDialog from external Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390367/java-swing-close-jdialog-from-external-thread)[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627656/how-to-prevent-joptionpane-showconfirmdialog-box-from-closing)

Answer in that post is as follows:

Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing

> By default, when the user clicks a JOptionPane-created button, the
>   dialog closes. But what if you want to check the user's answer before
>   closing the dialog? In this case, you must implement your own property
>   change listener so that when the user clicks a button, the dialog does
>   not automatically close.
>
> DialogDemo contains two dialogs that implement a property change
>   listener. One of these dialogs is a custom modal dialog, implemented
>   in CustomDialog, that uses JOptionPane both to get the standard icon
>   and to get layout assistance. The other dialog, whose code is below,
>   uses a standard Yes/No JOptionPane. Though this dialog is rather
>   useless as written, its code is simple enough that you can use it as a
>   template for more complex dialogs.
>
> Besides setting the property change listener, the following code also
>   calls the JDialog's setDefaultCloseOperation method and implements a
>   window listener that handles the window close attempt properly. If you
>   do not care to be notified when the user closes the window explicitly,
>   then ignore the bold code.

```
final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(
                "The only way to close this dialog is by\n"
                + "pressing one of the following buttons.\n"
                + "Do you understand?",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, 
                             "Click a button",
                             true);
dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(
    JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
        setLabel("Thwarted user attempt to close window.");
    }
});
optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(
    new PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
            String prop = e.getPropertyName();

            if (dialog.isVisible() 
             && (e.getSource() == optionPane)
             && (prop.equals(JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY))) {
                //If you were going to check something
                //before closing the window, you'd do
                //it here.
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    });
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);

int value = ((Integer)optionPane.getValue()).intValue();
if (value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    setLabel("Good.");
} else if (value == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    setLabel("Try using the window decorations "
             + "to close the non-auto-closing dialog. "
             + "You can't!");
}
```

Comment: So you mean I add a propertychangelistener to the OptionPane and execute my SQL statement there?

Comment: Yes you can try the same. Because you get the hold of the event there.